# How to combine several tables in a mysql query and rank based on total of a column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I have several tables I need help to generate a query string. I am currently querying each of the tables and combining the results in the frontend which is making too many requests to the backend

Below is the structure of my tables (See this [Sample sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49e4a0/1) )

**users**

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe |
| 2 | Peter | Parker |

**events**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New Year wake contest |
| 2 | Bright Monday contest |

**question**

| id | description | points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Some Question Here | 2 |
| 2 | Another Question Here | 4.5 |

A question can belong to many events while events can have many questions

**event_question**

| question_id | event_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |

Answers belong to a question

**answers**

| id | description | question_id | is_correct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Answer is 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Not True | 1 | 0 |

The final step is to save the info about an exam attempt

**attempts**

| user_id | attempt | question_id | answer_id | event_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 8 | 2 |

I need help with coming up with a query that will retrieve the rank of a specific contest.

Lets say `event_id = 1`

**Expected output**

For event with `id = 1` the rank will be

| user_id | first_name | last_name | points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Paul | Morphy | 13.5 |
| 4 | Bobby | Fisher | 9.5 |
| 1 | John | Doe | 9.5 |
| 2 | Peter | Parker | 6 |
| 3 | Alexander | Alekhine | 6 |

For event with `id = 2` the rank will be

| user_id | first_name | last_name | points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Bobby | Fisher | 7 |
| 1 | John | Doe | 6 |
| 2 | Peter | Parker | 6 |
| 5 | Paul | Morphy | 5 |
| 3 | Alexander | Alekhine | 3 |

`points` is the sum of points for the `questions` that a given user provided correctly

I am using **PHP (Laravel)** and **MySql**. A solution with Laravel eloquent or simply an SQL query are both welcomed

Comment: try to create new table called "event_user" have these columns event_id,user,id,points
and when user submit event questions fill this table and make relation belongsToMany on user Model (events) and same relation on event Model (users) .

Comment: @anasomush will that not be a repetition? and also will require a lot of administrative consideration such as what if the points for a particular question are adjusted, then there will be need to change points for each "event_user"

Comment: yes you have to handle update operation. but that will provide you a best performance and capability this is from my point of view.

Comment: What's your actual problem here? The data seems pretty simple. You should include your attempt so far

Comment: @JamesZ the 'actual problem' is that I am more of a frontend developer with some knowledge using Laravel for queries so my approach is as indicated in the sql_fiddle,simply query the data and return it to the frontend, and get the rank in the frontend, Is including this what you need?

Comment: How can Boby get 80 points, when he answered only 10 questions (`SELECT count(*)
FROM question_attempts
WHERE user_id=4;`), and the average points for a question is 2.25 (`SELECT AVG(points),MAX(points) FROM questions;`) with a max of 3.5 ? [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e03312/36)

Comment: @Luuk sorry this was another sample data, I had to remove most of the sample data to avoid too much data on the fiddle, the sample was to illustrate the ranking

Comment: Only use 1 set of 'sample data', and use the SAME sample data for your Fiddle as in your question.

Comment: Are you familiar with, and have you explored using, [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) [directives](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) for this?.

Comment: This is great! (I get to use comments to express opinions.) Another "front-end developer" starts  to understand the limitations of that specialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess each `id` column in each of your tables is unique, that is each table has no repeated `id` values. That's definitely the case in your fiddle.

And, I guess no user makes repeated attempts to answer a particular question in a particular event.

Here's a pure SQL query to get what you want. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kRKsYAg954msn7bebtgUpg/2)

```sql
SELECT question_attempts.event_id,
       users.id user_id, users.first_name, users.last_name,
       SUM(questions.points) points
  FROM question_attempts
  JOIN questions   ON question_attempts.question_id = questions.id
  JOIN answers     ON question_attempts.answer_id = answers.id
  JOIN users       ON question_attempts.user_id = users.id
 WHERE answers.is_correct = 1
 GROUP BY question_attempts.event_id,
         users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name
```

Why does this work?  Your `question_attempts` table ties all the other tables together.

- `JOIN questions ON question_attempts.question_id = questions.id` pulls in the question for each answer attempt. We need that because it says how many `points` the question is worth.
- `JOIN answers ON question_attempts.answer_id = answers.id` pulls in the answer for each attempt. We need that because we need to know whether the particular answer `is_correct`.
- `JOIN users ON question_attempts.user_id = users.id` gets us the users' names.

Then, the SUM / GROUP BY adds up the points for correct answer for each event and user.

This query gets back all your events and users. You can add

```
WHERE ...  AND question_attempts.event_id = 6
```

or some such thing to get the results for just one event.

And you can use

```
ORDER BY question_attempts.event_id,
         SUM(questions.points) DESC,
         users.id
```

to get your output in descending order of score (highest first) for each event.

Comment: Thanks, This was very helpful, I used your ideas to come up with the below https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f3nNf63Pvaop9x6qmfSz4T/0 thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This is example where triggers would come in handy. Use them to calculate Points directly into a table column. One you will have milions of rows and each time you gonna calculate this... over time it will get worst and worst.

Everytime you update answers you will update user row to update points.

Answer (score -1):

Because your problem seems to be in houw to use ranking, I created an example on your questions table, and added a RANK on the points:

It is an example how to do RANKing (actually DENSE_RANK) in MySQL 5.6. When you are using MySQL 8.0 then you should user [RANK or DENSE_RANK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank)

```
SET @R:=0; 
SET @P:=0;
SELECT 
   id,
   description,
   points,
   CASE WHEN @P=points THEN @R ELSE @R:=@R+1 END as `RANK`,
   @P:=points
FROM questions
ORDER BY points DESC
```

For output, see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e03312/64), or:

| id | description | points | RANK | @P:=points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | What was the first disease to be discovered | 3.5 | 1 | 3.5 |
| 10 | A child has more bones than an adult | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 8 | Average time to complete a Marathon is 2hrs | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 7 | An earthworm can grow back when cut | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | The statement a swarm of butterfly is valid | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | Sudan is the largest country in Africa | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | A cat dies 9 times | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | Blood color changes | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | Water is blue | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 9 | What is the value of one plus one divide two? | 1 | 4 | 1 |

Comment: I have updated the question with the correct output, you are ranking the question points, I need help with ranking the participants